# PCI-X card controlled by VM

Tags: virtual-machine, virtualization, pci-express, pci, linux-kvm

I have a PCI-X card which I would like to assign to one of my VM guests.

I am using Ubuntu 10.10, with libvirt and kvm.

Is there any way, of completely bypassing the host system, and routing all PCI-X interaction (drivers, interrupts, general ownership) to one of the VMs?

Answer (score 0):

I could easily do it using a CentOS 6.3 but not with Ubuntu 12.04.

CentOS is an OS provided by a community around Red Hat products. and Red Hat is the main sponsor of Kvm. I guess that's the explanation...

Check here : [the 28 simple steps to run pci-passthrough in a virtual machine with Spice](http://alapointe.degraeve.us/post/33244525132/28-simple-steps-to-run-pci-passthrough-in-a-virtual)